# Using dictionary key as the _id when using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a dictionary like so:

```py
a_dictionary = {
                'UniqueNumber': 1,
                'YearResults' : [],
               }
```

When I use:

```py
MyCollection.replace_one(
        {'UniqueNumber': a_dictionary['UniqueNumber']}, a_dictionary, upsert=True)
```

Mongodb is creating an `_id` field: _id: 5e467caa3cec0556ddcb3a41.

I don't want this, I want to use my UniqueNumber and have no _id field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation: [Insert document](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document)

> When a document is inserted a special key, "_id", is automatically added if the document doesn’t already contain an "_id" key. The value of "_id" must be unique across the collection

So in order to have your custom identifier you can add `_id` to the record you are inserting. Please note `The value of "_id" must be unique across the collection`

Hope it helps.